# Discord.py making a channel/retrieving it is returning a NoneType error

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a ticket command in my Discord bot that opens a private text channel for users to talk with staff members. I've also set up a database where users can change the Staff role and what message is sent, but that's not important for now. This is my code:

```
@bot.command(name="ticket", help="Sets up a ticket for you to use.")
async def ticket(ctx):
    db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT ticket_text FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    userticket = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), name=f"{ctx.author.name.lower()}-ticket")
    if userticket:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author.name}**, you already have a ticket set up! Wait for someone to respond to it.")
    else:
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT ticket_role_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
        result1 = cursor.fetchone()
        staff_role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=int(result1[0]))
        overwrites = {
            ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            staff_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        }
        await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"{ctx.author.name.lower()}-ticket", overwrites=overwrites)
        yourticket = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), name=f"{ctx.author.name.lower()}-ticket")
        plswaitticketem = discord.Embed(title=f" {result[0]}", color=0x21ffb1)
        plswaitticketem.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await yourticket.send(embed=plswaitticketem)
```

Since my code is really long, I won't put the entire thing here. When I run the bot and type the command in Discord, though, this is the error I get:

```
PS C:\Coding\MyDiscordpyBots\Jupiter> & C:/python3.8.5/python.exe c:/Coding/MyDiscordpyBots/Jupiter/mainjupiter.py
Jupiter is ready!
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3.8.5\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event       
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Coding/MyDiscordpyBots/Jupiter/mainjupiter.py", line 660, in on_command_error   
    raise error.original
  File "C:\python3.8.5\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Coding/MyDiscordpyBots/Jupiter/mainjupiter.py", line 914, in ticket
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"{ctx.author.name.lower()}-ticket", overwrites=overwrites)
  File "C:\python3.8.5\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 929, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.text, category, reason=reason, **options)
  File "C:\python3.8.5\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 832, in _create_channel
    'id': target.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Apparently, something in my code is a NoneType that is causing an issue. I found out that by removing the `overwrites=overwrites` part of the command where I make the private channel (`await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"{ctx.author.name.lower()}-ticket", overwrites=overwrites)`), the issue seems to go away, but then the text channel becomes public. How can I fix my overwrites? I tried a few other solutions, such as debugging my database, but nothing seems to work.

How could I fix this?

Comment: I think your bot doesn't have the permission to view the channel if its private, are you sure your bot has the correct perms?

Comment: I think it does, I gave it administrator perms and enabled all the other perms too.

Answer (score 0):

```
        staff_role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=int(result1[0]))
```

I think your problem might be `name=int(`. Name should be a string. If you're trying to get a role by its id, do `ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)`

Comment: Thats the problem yes, but this isn't the answer, how does he solve it?